# AsyncTask not executing properly according to logic

Tags: android, android-asynctask, openstreetmap

I'm having problems trying to download specific tiles for OSM in different zoom levels, based on a given set of places with their latitude and longitude values.

What I am trying to do is to determine the MapTile number for the top/bottom left and top/bottom right corners, and loop the numbers to download the tiles. For now I am trying to download zoom levels 1 above and 1 below the given zoom level in the constructor.

```
public class MapDownload extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

int zoom;
private ArrayList<GeoPoint> places;
private Coordinates topRight = new Coordinates(); // a java class I did for myself
private Coordinates bottomRight = new Coordinates();
private Coordinates topLeft = new Coordinates();
private Coordinates bottomLeft = new Coordinates();

public MapDownload(ArrayList<GeoPoint> placeList, int zoom){ 
    this.places = placeList;
    this.zoom = zoom;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        for (int w = zoom -1 ; w <= zoom +1; w++){

            double maxLat = 0.0;
            double maxLon = 0.0;
            double minLat = 0.0;
            double minLon = 0.0;

            for(GeoPoint point: places) {
                double lon = (double) ( point.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6 * 1.0);
                double lat = (double) (point.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6 * 1.0);
                    if(lat > maxLat) {
                        maxLat = lat;
                    }
                    if(lat < minLat || minLat == 0.0) {
                        minLat = lat;
                    }
                    if(lon> maxLon) {
                        maxLon = lon;
                    }
                    if(lon < minLon || lon == 0.0) {
                        minLon = lon;
                    }
            }
            topRight = topRight.gpsToMaptile(maxLon, maxLat, w); //top right
            bottomRight = bottomRight.gpsToMaptile(maxLon, minLat, w); //bottom right
            topLeft = topLeft.gpsToMaptile(minLon, maxLat, w); //top left
            bottomLeft = bottomLeft.gpsToMaptile(minLon, minLat, w); //bottom left

            for (int x = topLeft.getYTile(); x < bottomLeft.getYTile(); x++){
                for(int y = topLeft.getXTile(); y < bottomRight.getXTile(); y++){
                    try {
                        String urlStr = "http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/"+ w +"/"+y+"/"+x+".png";
                        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
                        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                        File newFileDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() 
                            + "/downloadMap/test/"+w+"/"+y);
                        newFileDir.mkdirs();
                        File newFile = new File(newFileDir, x+".png");
                        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
                        int read;
                        while ((read = in.read()) != -1) {
                            output.write(read);
                            output.flush();
                        }
                        urlConnection.disconnect();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("URL::: ERROR", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

In my MainActivity class, this is what I did to call this AsyncTask:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener, MapViewConstants {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        MapDownload mapDownload = new MapDownload(placeList, 12);
        mapDownload.execute("");  
    }
}
```

Things were fine when I did the loops for int x and int y (for a single zoom layer). However once I placed the 3rd loop with int w (to loop for different zoom levels), things started going haywire and it started downloading every single tile into the phone.

I have tested for the code logic separately (by printing the urlStr) and it does indeed work to determine the specific MapTiles needed for download. However the same codes wouldn't work when placed in this AsyncTask class, which led me to believe that such codes might have a problem with the implementation of AsyncTask.

Hope there is someone out there whom could point out my mistake. Thank you!

Comment: why do you compute minLat ... for every w ? aren't they the same ? (yes they are, the places array doesn't change from one to another)

Comment: nota : lats and lons can be negative. hence, maxLat = 0 and maxLon = 0 are not good init values. I recommend Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY (and POSITIVE_INFINITY for min init values)

Comment: more comment : iterate YTile on x and XTile on y is likely to confuse you at some point

Comment: Ah ok my bad, thanks for the tip. I can shift the calculation out of the w loop but I don't think that is the cause of the problem here? Will make the changes on my own copy anyway thank you!

Comment: I would say that if you don't have any point with lat > 0, you'll be downloading all tile up to lat = 0 (same goes for lon)

Comment: but when i tested out the exact same logic as normal java classes, it worked perfectly...

Comment: did you tested with the exact same code and with the exact same coordinates? If you run your algorithm with a set of 1 point (-80, -180), you'll see that mins are (-80, -180), but maxs are (0, 0), hence a whole bunch of tiles.

Comment: another point : for minLon, you test if **lon** == 0, meaning that if a point lon is 0, minLon becomes immediately 0, even if minLon is < 0 at this point (this should not cause extra tiles to be dled, more the opposite, but still)

Comment: Oh my gosh, what a simple mistake I made! Thank you so much! =)

Comment: I recommend you read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx if you haven't already. There is a lot of good information and code there for dealing with tile systems. It may help you with your calculations.